# Clarification on While loop - Infinite - Beginner learning

Tags: python-3.x, if-statement

I'm learning python programing. While practicing - "trying to check for an integer input is true as my target number. If it's not true repeat the process to check whether the input no: is correct."  I tried with while syntax, the stmt is not getting into the next condition to check the if statement.

```
guess_number = int(input('Enter number : '))
target_number = 65
if guess_number < target_number:
    print("Your guess is too small")
elif guess_number > target_number:
    print("Your guess is too large")
elif guess_number == target_number:
   print("Bingo")
else:
   print("guess_number")
```

Comment: You have to put the block u specified into a while loop and break the loop when it is equal to target number

Answer (score 1):

would this be what you want to do?

```
guess_number = int(input('Enter number : '))
target_number = 65
while guess_number != target_number: 
   if guess_number < target_number:
        print("Your guess is too small")
   elif guess_number > target_number:
        print("Your guess is too large")

   guess_number = int(input('Enter number : '))

print("Bingo")
```

You also might want to build in an error check to make sure the user input is an integer.